# Wordpress - Access a custom field value with PHP

Tags: php, wordpress

I am having trouble accessing a custom field on my Wordpress page.

I have a field for a user to upload an image file. The theme that I am using then displays the value of that image as just the image ID, instead of an image link. I display it using `{CUSTOM_FIELD_TestFile}` in the page editor.
I want it to display the actual image though, not the ID.

So, I created a PHP snippet that runs on the page, to do the converting.
If I use `<img src=" <?php echo wp_get_attachment_url( 1013 )?> ">` and I have the image ID hard coded (1013), it works perfectly.

However, I have had no luck getting the value of 'TestFile' into the PHP snippet.
I double checked the user_meta table and the meta_key for this file is indeed TestFile.

The viewing of the page is done usually when a user is not logged in. So, `get_current_user_id()` isn't an option, which means, I also can't use `get_user_meta()`.

If I use:

```
<?php 
$postId = get_the_ID();
echo $postId; 

$fileLink = get_metadata( "user", $postId, "TestFile");
echo $fileLink;
?>
```

I get "array" as a response. If I change it to `get_metadata( "user", $postId, "TestFile", true);` I get nothing.

The exact same results if I use `get_post_meta($postId, 'TestFile');` or `get_post_meta($postId, 'TestFile', true);`.

***Am I on the completely wrong track? Is there an easier way to do this?*** Or is there something that I should be doing with that "array" value that is being returned.

Thanks so much for any help you can offer.

Comment: `var_dump($fileLink)` and you'll see what's in your array.

Comment: Thanks so much! I ran var_dump and this is what I got:  array(0) { }

Comment: OK that means it's empty and your code didn't retrieve the correct data.

Comment: Indeed it does. Any suggestions on how to get the correct data?

Comment: Have you checked that `get_the_ID()` is indeed returning the correct value? Also, is your code within a WordPress loop or a single post page? What do you get if you `var_dump(the_meta())`? Also, have you tried `get_post_custom_values('TestFile')`?

Answer (score 0):

If you have added a custom field called `TestFile` in the editor, you should be able to get that in your template with:

```
$value = get_post_meta($postId, 'TestFile', true);
```

I'm not sure what you mean about the user being logged in or out, because custom fields belong to the post and have nothing to do with the user.

Assuming that works, you should be able to add the ID to your image element:

```
<img src="<?= wp_get_attachment_url($value); ?>">
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your response! However, as I mentioned, I get the same results if I use get_post_meta($postId, 'TestFile'); or get_post_meta($postId, 'TestFile', true);   
It's not returning anything.